# Element not aligning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am newbie to bootstrap, trying to get a make a template.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">        
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>       
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">

            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Tech Site</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
                <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
                <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse"> 
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>      
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

[image]

Top image is what i wanted, but, what i am getting is the below output,

[image]

As one can see in the image, the links are in the same line as the brand name, which i do not want, it should be in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Style like this.

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

to

```
 display:block;
```